# Shopify theme development locally, but would like to update the draft theme code and theme editor on the site

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-app

I connected my shopify account and pulled a theme which i am developing. The live theme and the current site content I would like to stay the same, while I am making changes in the theme editor and in the code through VScode. My issue is that the custom theme editor for the dev theme doesn't save the changes I make. How do I save those changes as well, or what should be my workflow?

I have tried to shopify theme push --unpublished --theme XYZ . But my changes from the theme editor didn't go through

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, working with Shopify theme locally from my system using CLI. When I hit save after making all the change, it shows "saved" but then I close the server and run it again, all the changes are gone.

The solution I found is while running `shopify theme dev` take another terminal on the same theme location and run  **`shopify theme pull -d`**

*Note: make sure while pulling the development environment is still running*